# Testflight shows wrong build(.ipa) for the first time running it second time it show the actual build(Application)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have uploaded a application using **EXPO** framework, In test flight am facing a issue that it shows another application for the initial time then when i restart the test flight and open it again i get to see that my original application opens in test flight. Even from the app store i got meta data rejection because they get to see my another app login screen there and the login creational i provided would never work there.

Comment: in `app.json` check *name* and *slug* if they are correct

Comment: Yes @Cherniv they are correct and the situation is that it only opens another app for the 1st time only then afterwards it opens the actual app.